# AngularJS Hashtags, Deep links and IE9

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am currently in a situation where I have to provide support for IE9, for an AngularJS app, while keeping hashtags out of my links (Links sent out from emails etc. whatever angular does client side, doesn't matter).

I've got to a point, where almost everything works, by using:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode true
.hashPrefix '!'
```

This works perfectly for everything, converting links:

```
example.com/whatever
```

into

```
example.com/index.html#!/whatever
```

Now I have a problem, where if I hit the route: `example.com`
(A url with no params at all), my application won't start, and I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
```

Everything works fine in browsers which supports the history API.

Comment: What version of AngularJS?

Comment: Are you using the correct [doctype](http://alistapart.com/article/doctype)? It might be running in IE7/IE8 mode in which indexOf would not be supported.

Comment: I'm using angular v1.2.16, and <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Have you setup URL rewrites server side?

Comment: No, everything is running through the ui-router.

Comment: I believe that's required, per the [docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).

Comment: Do you have a link or an explanation as to what needs to be rewritten?

Comment: I posted an answer that should get you going. I won't say it's a complete solution because getting routing working in < IE10 is a very unpleasant, but should get you headed in the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I figured out my problem.

We had the setting `base href` set to `index.html`, which would prepend index.html to all URLs in IE9 browsing.

When I changed the `base href` to `/` everything just works.

Answer (score -1):

When using HTML5Mode with ui-router, it's necessary to setup URL rewrites server side. How this is done is determined by your server side technology. A variety of methods are explained [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode).

For instance, IIS would use something like the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules> 
      <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                                 
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

The result is that all incoming requests will be routed to the root of the site by IIS which in turn will load the index.html page which presumably has your ng-app tag and angular.js references. This will cause client side routing to kick in (ui-router in this case) and you'll be up and running in HTML5 routing mode.